# Draw same bar trace chart with some delay(change in x-axis value) using plotly js

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, plotly, plotly.js

Our initial requirement is to receive data from server and perform some client side calculations and send calculated data to plotly to draw graph as shown in below image.

We have a new requirement to draw new trace on top of old trace with some delay which we receive from server. Additionally, need to add a new color or scatter lines to the portion of the old trace that is visible.

Below is the image which explains the same requirements

[image]

In the above image, trace3 chart is redrawn from 0.5 to 3.5 with delay of 0.5.

Below are the code(not complete code) we used to draw plotly chart for the initial requirements

```
let layout = {
  plot_bgcolor: phase.backgroundColor as Color,
  paper_bgcolor: '#f3f3f3',
  margin: { r: 0, l: 0, t: 30, b: 35 },
  legend: { traceorder: 'reversed' },
  showlegend: phase.showlegendValue,
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Pulse Width (ms): ' + Math.round(pulseWidthMs),
  },
} as Layout;

return {
  data: traceData,
  layout: layout,
  config: { responsive: true, displayModeBar: false },
};
```

trace obj after calculation

```
trace1 = {
    name: 'trace1',
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'lines',
    line: { shape: 'hv' },
    yaxis: `y${traces.length + 1}`,
    x: plotValues.xValues,
    y: plotValues.yValues,
    fill: 'tozeroy',
    hoverinfo: 'name',
} as unknown as PlotData
```

We tried different approaches and none of them are fit into our requirements. Also tried, layout stack / overlay approaches but not helpful.

We need some help to achieve this new requirement. Kindly provide your valuable inputs. Thanks in advance.